# The activity call relayout cotinually, but I could not find which code make it happen

Tags: android

I was working on a Android App which it's main activity contains a `PullToRefreshGridView` showing some items. I've toggled a breakpoint on my `Adapter` `getCount()` method and for my surprise i found out that it is being called a lot of times.

[image]

I've tried setting a lot of breakpoint throughout my code, but the debug process did not stop in any of those.

Is there any method or tools that could help me find the snippet of code that is causing this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi what is that in the picture?

Comment: Frame of callback,  in debug view